# How can I get parameters values from a lamba expression for my nifty cache extension?

Tags: asp.net, caching, lambda

First of all it might be worth looking at this question: 
[How can I cache objects in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445050/how-can-i-cache-objects-in-asp-net-mvc)

There some pseudo code that almost does what i want:

```
public class CacheExtensions
{
  public static T GetOrStore<T>(this Cache cache, string key, Func<T> generator)
  {
    var result = cache[key];
    if(result == null)
    {
      result = generator();
      cache[key] = result;
    }
     return (T)result;
   }
}
```

However, what I'd really like to do, is auto-generate the "key" from the generator. I figure i need to change the method signature to:

```
public static T GetOrStore<T>(this Cache cache,
                System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T>> generator)
```

I want to use the method name, but also any parameters and their values to generate the key. I can get the method body from the expression, and the paramter names (sort of), but I have no idea how to get the paramter values...?

Or am I going about this the wrong way? Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

```
public static class ICacheExtensions
{
    public static T GetOrAdd<T>(this ICache cache, Expression<Func<T>> getterExp)
    {
        var key = BuildCacheKey<T>(getterExp);
        return cache.GetOrAdd(key, () => getterExp.Compile().Invoke());
    }

    private static string BuildCacheKey<T>(Expression<Func<T>> getterExp)
    {
        var body = getterExp.Body;
        var methodCall = body as MethodCallExpression;
        if (methodCall == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The getterExp must be a MethodCallExpression");
        }

        var typeName = methodCall.Method.DeclaringType.FullName;
        var methodName = methodCall.Method.Name;
        var arguments = methodCall.Arguments
            .Select(a => ExpressionHelper.Evaluate(a))
            .ToArray();

        return String.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", 
            typeName, 
            methodName, 
            String.Join("|", arguments));
    }
  }
```

with this helper to evaluate nodes of an expression tree:

```
internal static class ExpressionHelper
    {
        public static object Evaluate(Expression e)
        {
            Type type = e.Type;
            if (e.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
            {
                var u = (UnaryExpression)e;
                if (TypeHelper.GetNonNullableType(u.Operand.Type) == TypeHelper.GetNonNullableType(type))
                {
                    e = ((UnaryExpression)e).Operand;
                }
            }
            if (e.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
            {
                if (e.Type == type)
                {
                    return ((ConstantExpression)e).Value;
                }
                else if (TypeHelper.GetNonNullableType(e.Type) == TypeHelper.GetNonNullableType(type))
                {
                    return ((ConstantExpression)e).Value;
                }
            }
            var me = e as MemberExpression;
            if (me != null)
            {
                var ce = me.Expression as ConstantExpression;
                if (ce != null)
                {
                    return me.Member.GetValue(ce.Value);
                }
            }
            if (type.IsValueType)
            {
                e = Expression.Convert(e, typeof(object));
            }
            Expression<Func<object>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(e);
            Func<object> fn = lambda.Compile();
            return fn();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The node evaluation is copy / pasted / edited from the IQToolkit project ;)

Answer (score 0):

When calling a function that produces a collection i want to cache i pass all my function's parameters and function name to the cache function which creates a key from it.

All my classes implement an interface that has and ID field so i can use it in my cache keys.

I'm sure there's a nicer way but somehow i gotta sleep at times too.

I also pass 1 or more keywords that i can use to invalidate related collections.