# cache a list of data asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I want to implement caching of a list pulled from the db. I've had a look at this:

[How can I cache objects in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445050/how-can-i-cache-objects-in-asp-net-mvc)

I have this in my code:

```
var addresses =  repository.GetAllAddresses();//returns IQueryable<string>
```

using the answer in the question above how can i cache this?, I have created the class CacheExtensions, but not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have the extension method it's a simple matter of using it (don't forget to bring the static class you have defined the `GetOrStore` method into scope by adding a using directive to the namespace containing it or you won't be able to see the `GetOrStore<T>` extension method):

```
IEnumerable<string> addresses = HttpRuntime
    .Cache
    .GetOrStore<IEnumerable<string>>(
        "addresses", 
        () => repository.GetAllAddresses().ToArray()
);
```

Things to note:

- We are using "addresses" as a cache key, so the result will be stored under this key.
- We are calling `.ToArray()` on the `IQueryable<string>` in order to eagerly fetch the addresses and store the results into the cache and not the query.