# How to cache database tables to prevent many database queries in Asp.net C# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-4

I build my own cms using Asp.net mvc 4 (c#), and I want to cache some database data, likes: localization, search categories (it's long-tail, each category have it's own sub and sub-sub categories),  etc..

It's will be overkill to query the database all the time, because it can be more than 30-100 queries for each page request, however the users update those database rarely

**So what is the best way  (performance and convenience) to do it?**

I know how use the OutputCache of the action, but it's not what I need in this situation , it's cache the html, but what I need is for example, that my own helper `@html.Localization("Newsletter.Tite")` will take the value of the language, or any another helper that interact with data etc.

I think (not really sure) that I need to cache the data I want, only when the application is invoke for the first time, and then work with the cache location, but I don't have any experience even about to it.

Comment: What are you currently doing and why is it not working?

Comment: Romoku, I do simple c# linq queries to the databse, and it's overkill because there are many requests for each page request

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could use the built-in [`MemoryCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) to store entire resultsets you have retrieved from the database.

A typical pattern:

```
MyModel model = MemoryCache.Default["my_model_key"] as MyModel;
if (model == null)
{
    model = GetModelFromDatabase();
    MemoryCache.Default["my_model_key"] = model;
}

// you could use the model here
```

Comment: is it's the best way? I can find a lot of ways, but I don't know what is the best

Comment: *Best* is a subjective notion. MemoryCache is quite extensible and is the new caching mechanism introduced in .NET 4.0. It can easily be extended to use a distributed cache such as memcached for example which is a must if you are running your site in a webfarm.

Comment: Then go ahead with MemoryCache.

Comment: Sounds great the webfarm support , I will use it!
 can the MemoryCache, cache entire database table?

Comment: MemoryCache doesn't know anything about database tables. It works with .NET objects. So in theory if you load your database table into some .NET object (or a collection of objects) you could then store it into the MemoryCache as shown in my answer.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov You say MemoryCache can be "extended to use a distributed cache such as memcached". Why would you? Why not just use MemCached directly via a .Net client? Just curious.

Comment: Because when you are writing a web application which is supposed to be deployed on a WebFarm (common case nowadays) I don't want to be storing information in-memory because the nodes of the web-farm won't be able to see this information and each node will keep a cache copy of the data which is a complete waste. In this case you should use distributed cache such as memcached.

Comment: I'm confused and possibly so are other people too. You suggested "extending" MemoryCache didn't you? Why would you "extend" MemoryCache over using MemCache directly?

Comment: Actually you should not extend MemoryCache. You should extend the ObjectCache. Memcached already provides an implementation that could directly be used. You are right. I didn't express myself correctly.

Comment: Can you please explain this statement **The main differences between the `Cache` and `MemoryCache classes` is that you can create multiple instances of the `MemoryCache class` for use in the same application and in the same `AppDomain` instance.**

Comment: @PKKG, the sentence seems pretty self explanatory. What additional explanation do you need? With MemoryCache you could create multiple instances. For example `new MemoryCache("my_region1")`, `new MemoryCache("my_region2")`, ...

Comment: what is the best way to store data in cache at client side? Does MemCached affect to performance?

Comment: is it singleton or scoped memorycache?

Answer (score 37):

I had to cache common database data like data that were displayed in drop downs. I used `MemoryCache`. And I used `Entity Framework code first` and `Autofac` for dependency injection.

Here is part of what I did in my solution, might not work for you but it worked for me, not perfect though but needs a lot of cleaning up to do.

My `ICacheManager` interface:

```
public interface ICacheManager
{
     T Get<T>(string key);

     void Set(string key, object data, int cacheTime);

     bool IsSet(string key);

     void Remove(string key);

     void Clear();
}
```

My `CacheManager` class:

```
public class CacheManager : ICacheManager
{
     private ObjectCache Cache
     {
          get
          {
               return MemoryCache.Default;
          }
     }

     public T Get<T>(string key)
     {
          return (T)Cache[key];
     }

     public void Set(string key, object data, int cacheTime)
     {
          if (data == null)
          {
               return;
          }

          CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
          policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(cacheTime);

          Cache.Add(new CacheItem(key, data), policy);
     }

     public bool IsSet(string key)
     {
          return (Cache.Contains(key));
     }

     public void Remove(string key)
     {
          Cache.Remove(key);
     }

     public void Clear()
     {
          foreach (var item in Cache)
          {
               Remove(item.Key);
          }
     }
}
```

An extension class for my caching:

```
public static class CacheExtensions
{
     public static T Get<T>(this ICacheManager cacheManager, string key, Func<T> acquire)
     {
          return Get(cacheManager, key, 60, acquire);
     }

     public static T Get<T>(this ICacheManager cacheManager, string key, int cacheTime, Func<T> acquire)
     {
          if (cacheManager.IsSet(key))
          {
               return cacheManager.Get<T>(key);
          }
          else
          {
               var result = acquire();

               cacheManager.Set(key, result, cacheTime);

               return result;
          }
     }
}
```

And this is how I would use it in my repository class. This method returns a list of all my banks which is displayed in a drop down.

```
public class BankRepository : RepositoryBase<Bank>, IBankRepository
{
     private readonly ICacheManager cacheManager;
     private const string BanksAllCacheKey = "banks-all";

     public BankRepository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory, ICacheManager cacheManager)
          : base(databaseFactory)
     {
          Check.Argument.IsNotNull(cacheManager, "cacheManager");

          this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
     }

     public IEnumerable<Bank> FindAll()
     {
          string key = string.Format(BanksAllCacheKey);

          return cacheManager.Get(key, () =>
          {
               var query = from bank in DatabaseContext.Banks
                           orderby bank.Name
                           select bank;

               return query.ToList();
          });
     }
}
```

I hope this helps. It's a very simple implementation but it works for me. There are many articles online on how to use a caching strategy in `ASP.NET MVC`. Just `Google` it.

Comment: Great answer. I'd love to use this approach. Allows the ability to "clear the cache" when the developer wants to (I'm always fighting with my durations for my [OutputCache] attributes...I'd love it even more if you could place a duration on this implementation...

Comment: Nevermind, answered my own question here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.defaultcachecapabilities(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: great, but i don't want to cache when acquire return null , 0 or empty IEnumerable , how to fix the extension method? thx

Comment: You can clean up by checking open source shopping platform **nopcommerce** , they use their own `CacheManager` , please check their [source](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce)  and also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445050/how-can-i-cache-objects-in-asp-net-mvc) post , hope helps.

Comment: MVCForum also uses CacheManger,  It's open source on Github.

Comment: This seems to be a very good approach for many reasons, I'm going to give it a try to see how flexible it can be in a real solution

Answer (score 4):

There are several things to consider here before choosing your implementation of caching, but one of the main things you have to decide is at what point do you want the caching to occur - at data access, the model creation or UI generation? One or all of these places?

You have several options but for general data caching you can use the [`System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx), or for something much more flexible and rewarding you can look at an implementation using NoSQL like [Redis](http://redis.io/).

You could use `MemoryCache` for data caching, but use Redis for caching aggregates making up your view models. If you went with Redis, you could of course handle all your caching using this. The benefit being that all your data would become persistent across application restarts. The disadvantage being that it becomes an additional requirement for running your CMS.

Other things to factor in are consistency (using some IoC would help) and allowing data to be voided once it updates. Therefore having some means of updating the cache.

With regards to the *best* approach, in your case if you are creating a new CMS application, start small/simple and build up in steps. You may not get it perfect first time but as long as you are consistent and clear in your approach it should be easy to build upon what you  have done or swap out and try something different/better.